# OSX NSVisualEffectView Decrease Blur Radius

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsvisualeffectview

I have an NSVisualEffect with as the background for my mac app. I want the visual effect view to blur whatever it is over, but the vibrant dark is just looks like a black view. How do I decrease the blur radius so that I can see the background more clearly. If this is not possible is NSVisualEffect, then how do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: I voted to "close as duplicate" because the other post has an answer that can work, and a question with an illustration. This one was obviously asked first, and so the other is the true "duplicate", but is more useful to someone looking for an answer.

Comment: Hello, I'm glad the other poster could get an answer. I have marked this question as a duplicate to help send people along to the correct answer.